# problem with popen

Tags: c++, linux

I have a strange problem. I have 2 binaries by the name cpp and another is called mnp_proxy_server.

cpp will start mnp_proxy_binary by calling a method **executeScript**. The code of this method is

```
int executeScript(string script, unsigned int scriptTmOut)
{
fd_set readfd;
const int BUFSIZE = 1024;
//stringstream strBuf;
char buf[ BUFSIZE];
time_t startTime = time(NULL);
struct timeval tv;
int ret, ret2 = 0;

FILE * pPipe = popen(script.c_str(), "r");
if (pPipe == NULL)
{
//        cout << "popen() failed:"<< strerror(errno) << endl;
    return -1;
}

while(1)
{
    FD_ZERO(&readfd);
    FD_SET(fileno(pPipe), &readfd);

    /** Select Timeout Hardcode with 1 secs **/
    tv.tv_sec = scriptTmOut;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    ret = select(fileno(pPipe)+1, &readfd, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if(ret < 0)
    {
    //          cout << "select() failed " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    }
    else if (ret == 0)
    {
    //        cout << "select() timeout" << endl;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        //cout << "Data is available now" <<endl;
        if(FD_ISSET(fileno(pPipe), &readfd))
        {
            if(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), pPipe) != NULL )
            {
                //cout << buf;
                //strBuf << buf;
            }
            /** No Problem if there is no data ouput by script **/
            #if 1
            else
            {
                //ret2 = -1;
               // cout << "fgets() failed " << strerror(errno) << endl;
                break;
            }
            #endif
        }
        else
        {
            ret2 = -1;
  //          cout << "FD_ISSET() failed " << strerror(errno) << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    /** Check the Script-timeout **/
    if((startTime + scriptTmOut) < time(NULL))
    {
    //    cout<<"Script Timeout"<<endl;
        break ;
    }
}
pclose(pPipe);

return ret2;
```

}

cpp is a server which listens on various ports 7001 and 7045. Once mnp_proxy_server is started it connects to 7001 port and starts sending messages.

Now coming to the problem. when i send ctr^c signal to cpp the signal is propagated to mnp_proxy_server and if i kill cpp process then all the ports on which cpp was listning now becomes the part of mnp_proxy_server process.

output of netstat after killing cpp process

[root@punith bin]# netstat -alpn | grep mnp_pr

**tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7045                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN**      26186/mnp_proxy_ser

**tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7001                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN**      26186/mnp_proxy_ser

I know it has something to do with the way I am executing the startup script of mnp_proxy_server through cpp.

There is a signal handler in both the binaries. And also to exit the socket select when ctr^c is pressed I have used pipes in select, so when ctr^c is pressed i close the write end of the   pipe so that select is notified and select comes out and breaks the run loop.

Both of them are written in c++ and I am using rhel
Any clue will greatly help me in solving this. Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the flag CLOEXEC on the server sockets of cpp so that they are closed in the child process:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
```

While using socket like in your processes, I would suggest use fork and exec instead of popen to be able to close or manage all sockets between fork and exec, but the flag CLOEXEC might be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: you may also need to call setpgrp().

Comment: Can I apply CLOEXEC  on Pipes too ?

Comment: Yes you can. You have to apply it to fileno(pPipe)

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Benoit Thiery it worked like charm. Just one more query. Adding setpgrp() to mnp_proxy process can get me out of ctr^c signal getting navigated from parent to child but it is not fesable to add this to all the process that cpp is going to start, because we dont have control over their code. So do you have any fix for this.

Comment: Yes, if you use fork and exec instead of popen, then you can call setpgrp directly in cpp process between fork and exec method calls. In this case, setpgrp is executed in the child process and will still be valid when you exec with the other executable.

Comment: Thanks I just did the same


pid_t pid = fork();

if ( pid ==0)

{

  setpgrp();


int i=open("/dev/null",O_RDWR|FD_CLOEXEC);

dup2(i,STDOUT_FILENO);

dup2(i,STDERR_FILENO);

close(i);

execlp("./run.sh",(char *) 0);

}

Comment: Thanks a ton :) Benoit Thiery well i never treaded fcntl part before, I think now I have to.

Comment: After above changes I see that the fd which is received after socket accept is also passed to the child, so i did the following to close all fd in child process.
for (int i=getdtablesize();i>=0;--i) close(i);